# Async Storage can't retrive data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asyncstorage

I'm currently creating an app using react native and async storage, but there's a problem when I add the new data, it can't show it on the screen until I ctrl+s the code file, but I want that when I add the new data and go back to the screen, it must show on it. I'm new with this so if you know the problem or solutions please help me, thank u in advance.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      data1 = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
      obj = Object.fromEntries(data1);
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        obj[key] = JSON.parse(obj[key]);
        data2.push(obj[key]);
      });
      setData(data2);
      console.log('DATA:' + data2);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Err: ', error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Are you saying that, ***during development***, that you don't see the current code being rendered until you ***save*** the changes so the app rebuilds and can rerender with those changes? This is generally how it works. You makes changes to code and save them, the app is rebuilt and hot-reloaded, and the app reloads/remounts so the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are coming back this screen, useEffect is not called hence data is not fetched fom async storage.

**Solution One**

To call useEffect every time screen is loaded, you can use `useFocusEffect` like this.

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

```
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      getData();
    }, [])
  );
```

**Solution Two**

another way you can call useEffect on screen load is with `useIsFocused` hook,

```
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
```

```
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    useEffect(() => {
       getData();
    }, [isFocused]);
```